# Rails gem/plugin that gives suggestions how to optimize your DB queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, query-optimization, rubygems

Some time ago I saw in a screencast showing a gem or plugin, which was able to suggest how to optimize your Rails DB queries, like where to use **include** or **add an index** and so on... Now I can't remember which screencast that was, but maybe somebody knows what I am talking about, I mean that gem/plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I have found it was on this [screencast](http://nr-content.s3.amazonaws.com/railslab/videos/19-ScalingRails-On-The-Edge-part-1.mp4), and it is called [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking about https://github.com/eladmeidar/rails_indexes , possibly https://github.com/samdanavia/ambitious_query_indexer .

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Was it [rails_best_practices](https://github.com/flyerhzm/rails_best_practices)?

Answer (score 0):

Now You can use my newly created [gem 'query_optimizer'](https://rubygems.org/gems/query_optimizer)

You can optimize queries as `Post.optimize_query(:comments)`